# Android - Load image from URL not working

Tags: android

please help me with these code, It doesn't show image from URL.

And another question, how to debug each functions such as "url.openConnection", "getInputStream".... to confirm they work well or not?

Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        // ImageView
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        mainLayout.addView(imgView);

        bitmap = loadImage("https://www.google.com.vn/logos/doodles/2014/dian-fosseys-82nd-birthday-5702250374627328-hp.jpg");
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }

    public Bitmap loadImage(String src)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            input.close();
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please add mainlayout's code please

Comment: also need to set layout parameters for ImageView

Comment: main layout is linearlayout and have no any component. I created them in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing network communications on the main thread, and assuredly getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because of it.

While you could implement an AsyncTask to manage your network calls, I would strongly suggest using a networking-capable image library to do all the grunt work for you.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I use this code from this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmYJBhz1gmk, I see him use in main thread....

Comment: NO, it's not get any NetworkOnMainThreadException, program run well but doesn't show any image!

Comment: If you are encountering problems before running your `loadImage(...)` method, check your stack trace to find out what's going wrong. Regardless, you *are* bound to run into a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on `connection.connect();` if you are calling that on your main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good idea to choose [ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library rather than doing all this nitty gritty stuff yourself. It is not optimised and error prone too.